# How to include conditional logic in a prepared statement in a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

We have a MySql stored procedure which includes the following:

```
 SET @queryString = (SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE Table2 t ",
 "JOIN vTable1 v ",
"ON t.id.=v.id ",
 "SET t.sub_id_track = 1, t.prefix = '", newPrefix,"',",
 " t.sub_id = ", vIndex,
 ";"));
 
 PREPARE update_sql FROM @queryString;

 EXECUTE update_sql;
```

This works well.

We now need to change it so that

If `newPrefix` is contains any value, then

```
SET t.sub_id_track = 1
```

but if `newPrefix` is null or empty, then

```
SET t.sub_id_track = 0
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this a prepared query at all, given there are no dynamic parts except for values? You could just use your local variables in a non-prepared UPDATE statement. Also why do you `SET t.sub_id` twice in the same update? Are you sure you have transcribed this correctly?

Comment: Also you have an SQL injection vulnerability as you copy `newPrefix` into the query string. Not sure why you are not using query parameters to protect agains that.

Comment: Yes, has made a mistake in transcription and corrected question, thank you for pointing this out

Comment: Still doesn't look right. Should `ON tid.=v.id` be `ON t.id=v.id`?

Comment: yes, corrected, thanks

Comment: `ON t.id.=v.id` is still not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have a few comments:

- Your prepared query has an SQL injection vulnerability.
- There's no reason you need to run this as a prepared query in the first place.

I suggest this alternative:

```
UPDATE Table2 t
JOIN vTable1 v ON t.id = v.id
SET t.sub_id_track = IFNULL(NULLIF(newPrefix, ''), 1, 0), 
    t.prefix = newPrefix, 
    t.sub_id = vIndex;
```

No PREPARE/EXECUTE required. No SQL injection vulnerability. And it handles the conditional you described.

But I wonder if you intended there to be a `WHERE` clause in there? This will apply the UPDATE to every row.